Store output of command history
Is there some way to record not only the commands that I type in my terminal, but also their ouput? Is there maybe something that I can add to my .bashrc that could act similar to passing all commands through tee?

script. There is probably a duplicate question here somewhere, but searching is hard due to the legion of questions about shell scripts. Does this answer your question? Terminal output history?

@KamilMaciorowski Yes, the script command seems to be exactly what I am looking for. However when I add this to my .zshrc, it will start an infinite loop, because after calling script it will start a new session using the zshrc calling script again etc. Do you have any idea?

The question is tagged bash and bashrc, but now we're talking about .zshrc. Inconsistency does not help.

To prevent infinite regress you need to define a base case / termination condition. A simple method here would be to test for a shell variable that you export when you run script (eg. [ -n "$InScript" ] || InScript=yes script )
